# Handling the cretion of a new Object in VueJs (CRUD) including checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Good day developers , in this shopcard i'm building , im trying now to add a new product to the collection of sale  elements .Lets say that my json got from back end has this structure:

```
"products": [
    {
      "product_provider": "tupac shakur",
      "rate": 3,
      "product_image": [
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      ],
      "product_id": 1,
      "product_price": 153.4,
      "product_stock": 26,
      "product_description": "Wood cutter ",
      "product_name": "Chain Saw",
      "product_category": [
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Good"
        },
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Danger"
        },
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Homer"
        }
      ],
      "people_buying_this_product": "Jack Ripper"
    },
 ]
```

then working on adding products i just made this html tag where in i just emulate the structure of the json object creating a form which once submited might pass its data to the vuex modifiying the variable which contains all products in sale, including a check box input to add Categories to the product im building(i just post the checkbox part cause is where the issue origins)

```
<v-layout v-for="(option,index) in ProductAdded.Categories" :key="index">
   <v-flex xs12>
     <div>
      <input name="id of product" label="id of product"type="checkbox" @click="option.selected = !option.selected"/>
      <label>{{ option.value }}</label>
     </div>
   </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

My data return was kind of;

```
 data() {
    return {

      thisCurrent: null,

      ProductAdded: {
        description: "",
        upload_image3: "",
        upload_image2: "",
        upload_image1: "",
        unities: 0,
        price: 0,
        name: "",
        Categories: [
          { id: 1, value: "Miscellaneous", selected: true },
          { id: 2, value: "Homer", selected: true },
          { id: 3, value: "Electronic", selected: false },
          { id: 4, value: "Internet", selected: false },
          { id: 5, value: "Kids", selected: true },
          { id: 6, value: "Donas", selected: false },
          { id: 7, value: "Sports", selected: false },
          { id: 8, value: "Horror", selected: false}
        ]
      },

    };
  },
```

the using this object in the data i created a method which dispatch a vuex action that might push this object to the variable that contains all product on sale :

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchAllProducts", "addProductSale"]),
    addProductOnSale(thisCurrent) {
      this.$store.dispatch("addProductSale", this.ProductAdded);
    },

  },
```

And then in Vuex call that action as well ass its mutations and getters:

```
VUEX

State:{
allProducts: {},
},

Mutations:{
settingProductSale(state,currentProduct){
      state.allProducts.products.push(currentProduct)
    }
},
getters:{
getAllProducts: state => state.allProducts,
}
```

And my problem then would be here in the action , building the object to send to mutations , cause all elements can be easily frame but no the product_category, that comming from the back end is a array of objects with same key and differents values , which in comparison with the one i return in data that leans on check or unchecked checkboxes:

```
addProductSale({commit,getters},currentProduct){
      console.log(currentProduct);

      let createdProductSale={
        product_provider:getters.getAllProducts.user.user_name,
        product_rate:0,
        product_image:[currentProduct.upload_image3,currentProduct.upload_image2,currentProduct.upload_image1],
        product_id: 0,
        product_purchases:0,
        product_price:Number(currentProduct.price),
        product_stock:Number(currentProduct.unities),
        product_description:currentProduct.description,
        product_name: currentProduct.name,
        product_category: currentProduct.Categories.---from here i don't know how to build this part of 
                                                       the object in order to make it to be exactly the 
                                                       same  than the structure came from JSON passing 
                                                       only those objects who has been checked
                                                       (selected true) in my-building ofject-form
        people_buying_this_product: 0,

      }
      commit("settingProductSale",createdProductSale)
    }
  }
```

My issue is in the product_category, cause honestly can't imagine the way of passing my checkbox checked elements into its object array just as the same way the JSON structure demands.
Please could somebody give me an idea about what i should do ?'
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

`product_category: currentProduct.Categories.filter(option => option.selected)`?

or maybe I didn not understand and you want:

`product_category: currentProduct.Categories.filter(option => option.selected).map(option => {categories_of_product: option.value})`

?

Comment: yes , but also wandering how could i get that response in the same format the  original objects gives , i mean

Comment: "product_category": [
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Good"
        },
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Danger"
        },
        {
          "categories_of_product": "Homer"
        }
      ],

Comment: Response is something a server send you, so I don't understand what you mean by that. My second example will format the `product_category` object into `[{categories_of_product: "Miscellaneous"}, {categories_of_product: "Homer"}...]` containing entries only for options selected === true.. If that is not what you want then I don't understand, I'm sorry.